# Paso de parámetro tipo vector puntero en c++

Tags: c++

Pero me sale un error en el primer parámetro, me podrían decir en que estoy mal.

```cpp
void MaxMin(float *v[], int primero,int ultimo)
{
    int central,i,j;
    float *pivote;

    central = (primero+ultimo) / 2;
    pivote = *(v+central);
    i = primero;
    j = ultimo;

    do{
        while(*(v+i) < pivote) i++;
        while(*(v+j) > pivote) j++;

        if(i<=j){
            aux = *(v+i);
            *(v+i) = *(v+j);
            *(v+j) = aux;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else{

        }

    }while(i<=j);

    if(primero < j){
        MinMax(v,primero,j);
    }

    if(i < ultimo){
        MinMax(v,i,ultimo);
    }

}
```

De esta forma invoco la función:

```c
MinMax(*datos,0,tam-1);
```

Comment: ¿Qué error sale? ¿Podrías agregar el código completo (del main) de la forma como invocas a la función `MinMax`?

Comment: En dónde está `*datos`?

Comment: Me sale     ¨¨un argumento de tipo float no es compatible con un parametro tipo float **´´

Comment: *datos es global y esta asi

Comment: void Pedir_Datos(){
    cout<<"\nCuantos digitos usaras: "; cin>>tam;

    datos = new float[tam];

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<"\nDato #"<<i+1<<": "; cin>>*(datos+i);
    }
}

Comment: Agrega los detalles en la misma pregunta, no lo hagas en los comentarios.

Comment: preferir `arreglo[indice]` sobre `*(arreglo+indice)`.

Answer (score 1):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), las formaciones<sup>1</sup> se transforman implícitamente en punteros cuando se pasan a una función.

Podemos comprobarlo con un código que nos imprima los tipos de datos:

```
template<typename T>
void chivato(T) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
```

Si a la función `chivato` le pasamos una formación, [veremos esto](https://tio.run/##Ncw/C4JAGIDxufdTvNCgDoGterhEQYtFXENUHMd51IH3B30VQ/zslkPj7xkeFcJG1dK95nltnKq7SiMzvqVGS1sAkLahlqQZfYJ20mrkBfTeVKjeppfkY57giC1VWaZ8R8gYCnG@7Dm/icO13PHjqRRiydHDRTlOAMYRWmlcnMAIq0XDfZs@c1j9n0PyQ6OpaxymOUzz/AU):

```
int x[10];
chivato(x);
```

Imprime: `void chivato(T) [T = int *]`. Así que una formación se pasa como puntero a una función, eso quiere decir que estas dos funciones son equivalentes:

```
void función(int *f);
//           ^^^^^ <---- Puntero a entero
void función(int f[]);
//           ^^^^^^^ <---- Formación de enteros
```

El parámetro `int *f` y el parámetro `int f[]` expresan lo mismo: un puntero. Así que ahora llegamos a tu función:

```
void MaxMin(float *v[], int primero,int ultimo)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^ <---- ¿Qué es esto?
```

Tu primer parámetro es una formación (`[]`) de punteros a coma flotante (`float *`), como sabemos que las formaciones son punteros, podemos concluir que el primer parámetro es un puntero a un puntero a coma flotante: `float **`. Seguramente querías hacer una de estas dos cosas:

```
void MaxMin(float *v, int primero,int ultimo)
//          ^^^^^^^ <---- Puntero a valores en coma flotante
void MaxMin(float v[], int primero,int ultimo)
//          ^^^^^^^^^ <---- Formación de valores en coma flotante
```

---

- <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en Inglés *arrays*.